# JSON.stringify differently than the example

Tags: javascript, html, json

I use [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) jQuery plugin to work with ajax tables. I want to send a POST request with JSON data in it. I use JSON.stringify to turn my data into JSON. It produces the result like this:

```
[
  {"name":"sEcho","value":1},
  {"name":"iColumns","value":9},
  {"name":"sColumns","value":""},
  {"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0}
...]
```

Though I want it to be like this:

```
{"sEcho":1, "iColumns":9, "sColumns":"", "iDisplayStart":0} ...
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may iterate over your data and build the desired structure before `JSON.stringify`-ing it:

```
var data = [{"name":"sEcho","value":1},{"name":"iColumns","value":9},{"name":"sColumns","value":""},{"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0}];

var options = {};
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  var key = data[i].name;
  var val = data[i].value;
  options[key] = val;
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(options);
```

You may also save a couple of lines and make it looks a bit nicer using jQuery `each` method:

```
var options = {};
$.each(data, function(){
  options[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Comment: @SergeyBasharov, Added some sugary ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your target browser supports ECMA-262 5th Edition (JavaScript 1.8.5), as most *modern* browsers do, you can use the [array "reduce" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```javascript
var data = [{"name":"sEcho","value":1},{"name":"iColumns","value":9},{"name":"sColumns","value":""},{"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0}];

var obj = data.reduce(function(a,x){a[x.name]=x.value;return a;}, {});
JSON.stringify(obj); // '{"sEcho":1, "iColumns":9, ...}'
```

Comment: I've really not realized the day we can use it is almost (if not already) here ;) The only sad part is Internet Explorer 8 and bellow that's still used too much to be ignored...